# How to create button in javascript to preform flip of card on click

Tags: javascript

.thecard:hover {
transform: rotateY(180deg)
}

I want to perform this transform when the user will click on the card. I want to know how to make a javascript button that can perform this function when the user will click on a card.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the  the  Javascript API `element.animate()` to add your keyframe animations and set how you want them to work. I would advise using a site like `caniuse`to see what browsers are compatible with the API.

```js
let animation = document.getElementById("card")

//If you just want to click on the card to flip it
animation.addEventListener("click", turnCard)

function turnCard (){
animation.animate([
  // keyframes
  { transform: 'perspective(400px) rotateY(0)' }, 
  { transform: 'perspective(400px) rotateY(180deg)' }
], { 
  // timing options
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: 1
})
}


//Using a button to flip the card
const cardFlipper = () =>{
  animation.animate([
  { transform: 'perspective(400px) rotateY(0)' }, 
  { transform: 'perspective(400px) rotateY(180deg)' }
], { 
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: 1
})
}
```

```css
#card{
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
 </div>
  <button onclick="cardFlipper()">Flip Card</button>
```